# How is Oracle Pack for Eclipse checking the domain?

Tags: eclipse, weblogic, eclipse-kepler, weblogic12c

I am using **Eclipse Kepler** with **Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse 12.1.2.3** and a Weblogic 12.1.1 server. When setting up the server I get

```
An older version domain is detected.
Click here to upgrade it with Upgrade Wizard.
```

I am quite sure that this message is misleading. I have a Weblogic 12 domain but I edited the scripts a bit to use environment variables for domain home and wlserver home instead of having the paths hard coded in the files. So I am able to create a copy of the domain and just change some environment variables to use it.

I am able to start the domain from command line using the `startWeblogic.sh` file, so it is working in general. Only Eclipse does not accept it.

Does anybody know what Eclipse is checking for when setting up the server domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WL_HOME` setting in `setDomainEnv` has to be a full qualified path to an existing `wlserver` folder. It must not be constructed out of environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

it was showing error when I was using directory domain as ...../base-domain/config
NO error when I used .../base-domain in directory domain. Web logic is searching for config folder

Comment: when i added "config.xml" in the folder domains\base_domain, i got this error. Once i removed it, the error was gone.